# Redux - how to combine multiple mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm developing a react-native / redux app, it contains a few Reducer files that I'm able to combine using *combineReducers()*. In order to manage the code and keep it maintainable, these files also contain *mapDispatchToProps* entries (I've done this because dispatch functions are closely related to Reducers) something like:

```
export const counterMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
        decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
    }
}
```

and

```
export const statusMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setStatus: (text) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATUS', status: text }),
    }
}
```

If possible I'd like to take the outputs of these mapDispatchToProps and combine them so that I get a function that produces the following, which can then be used when connecting to my Redux store:

```
export const appMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        increment: () => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' }),
        decrement: () => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' }),
        setStatus: (text) => dispatch({ type: 'SET_STATUS', status: text }),
    }
}
```

I guess my question effectively comes down to: how do I write a *combineMapDispatchToProps({counterMapDispatchToProps, statusMapDispatchToProps, ...})* function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these functions just return an object (which is then handled by the Consumer HOC) you can use ES6 spreading -

```
export const appMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        ...counterMapDispatchToProps(dispatch),
        ...statusMapDispatchToProps(dispatch),
    }
}
```

You can add more functions to this, and of course import them from other files.

---

If you need ES5, you can use Object.assign to similar effect:

```
export const appMapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
    return Object.assign(counterMapDispatchToProps(dispatch), statusMapDispatchToProps(dispatch));
}
```

Comment: That works, however I found I had to alter it slightly to:

export const appMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        ...counterMapDispatchToProps(dispatch),
        ...statusMapDispatchToProps(dispatch),
    }
}

Comment: @MichaelO'Connor Yikes, how did I miss that... nice one, I'll update the answer